# Scale multiple Text layers one point down?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, text, font-size

I'm on Photoshop CC 2017. I make a lot of UI design and I have come across this...

I want to scale down multiple text layers one point at once. From 22pt to 21pt for example, without having to go to each text layer and change the value there. 
Is this possible?

Comment: Scale thel or change the font size? Scaling them will make them slightly blurry.

Comment: I assume the text layers have different font sizes?

Answer (score 1):

To change the font size, select all of the text layers in the layers panel, by holding down CTRL (Command on Mac) as you click each one. This will make a multiple layer selection.

Then select the Text Tool, then in the tool options along the top, change the font size. The size will be applied to all the selected text layers.

[image: Screenshot Changing Font Size on Multiple layers]